# Apache Camel And Printing Producer

Tags: printing, apache-camel, consumer

This one should be simple but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get it running. What I want to do is read files from a folder and send them to a printer.

So I had a look at the documentation for the printer component in Camel and it seemed straight forward.

I produced the following DSL route:

```
  <camelContext trace="false" id="blueprintContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
  <route id="printSpoolRoute">
    <from uri="file:d:/printspool?delay=1000&amp;move=.done/printed/${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/${file:onlyname.noext}_DONE_${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.${file:name.ext}&amp;readLock=changed&quot;"/>
    <to uri="lpr:localhost/default?flavor=DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM&amp;mimeType=AUTOSENSE&amp;mediaSize=iso-a4"/>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

When I start it up I get the following exception:

`[         Blueprint Extender: 1] BlueprintCamelContext          ERROR Error occurred during starting Camel: CamelContext(blueprintContext) due Failed to create Producer for endpoint: Endpoint[lpr://localhost/default?flavor=DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM&mediaSize=iso-a4&mimeType=AUTOSENSE]. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateProducerException: Failed to create Producer for endpoint: Endpoint[lpr://localhost/default?flavor=DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM&mediaSize=iso-a4&mimeType=AUTOSENSE]. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException`

If the exception had more detail I might be able to look for something so I suspect I made a mistake in the URI of the printing producer.

While I am looking at the URI of the printer producer I just wanted to check if my understanding of the URI is correct when using a network printer.

Let assume I want to produce documents on a network printer connected to a server call SRV-07 with a name of HP LaserJet 4104 will the following URI be correct:

```
<to uri="lpr:SRV-07/HP LaserJet 4104?flavor=DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM&amp;mimeType=AUTOSENSE&amp;mediaSize=iso-a4"/>
```

I am worried about dashes and spaces in the name and someone that has worked with this component before could shed some light here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right leaving this here for reference.

Answer is that the `mediaSize` parameter must be specified according to the documentation found at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/MediaSizeName.html) link. I had the parameter as `iso-a4` instead of `ISO_A4`. Maybe the camel developers could give a little more descriptive exception here.

Also the question about the URI for network printers does work as I have specified.